# Completar ancho datagridview

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, .net, datagridview, vb

Tengo una aplicación la cual utiliza un datagridview para mostrar datos recogidos de SQL. Para la visualización correcta de este datagridview utilizo esto:

```
        DatagridView.DefaultCellStyle.Font = New Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 10)
        DatagridView.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill
        DatagridView.ReadOnly = True
        DatagridView.Columns(0).HeaderText = "ID"
        DatagridView.Columns(1).HeaderText = "Nombre"
        DatagridView.Columns(2).HeaderText = "Nombre Equipo"
        DatagridView.Columns(3).HeaderText = "NºCamiseta"
        DatagridView.Columns(4).HeaderText = "Codigo"
        DatagridView.ClearSelection() 
        DatagridView.RowHeadersVisible = False 
        For k = 0 To DatagridView.Rows.Count - 1
            DatagridView.Rows(i).Height = 50
        Next
    End Sub
```

Al cargar el Load del formulario llamo a esa función con el Datagridview que necesito, pero la primera vez no funciona, tengo que volver entrar en otra pestaña y luego volver a entrar y ya funciona

Sabéis porque puede ser?